# May I pay "in cash" or just "cash" without in?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the right phrase - May I pay "in cash" or may I "pay cash"?

Comment: "Pay cash" is acceptable and well-received.

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: But, perhaps more importantly, you need to understand the difference between *write* and *right*!

Comment: Can it be decided whether 'cash' in _pay cash_ is a DO or an adverbial objective?

Comment: Many roads lead to Rome. Many cultures lead to NYC.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be an entire family of expressions involving *pay* + [form of money] that permit English speakers to use either "pay [form of money]" or "pay in [form of money]." For example:

> *pay cash* & *pay in cash*
>
> *pay hard currency* & *pay in hard currency*
>
> *pay dollars* & *pay in dollars*
>
> *pay ready money* & *pay in ready money*
>
> *pay silver* & *pay in silver*

The dual acceptability seems to break down in situations where English speakers would normally use *by* in place of *in*. For example:

> *pay by check/cheque* but not *pay check/cheque*
>
> *pay by credit card* but not *pay credit card*

Members of the first set of phrases remain idiomatically acceptable (in U.S. English, anyway) when you substitute *with* for *in*:

> *pay with cash*
>
> *pay with hard currency*
>
> *pay with dollars*
>
> *pay with ready money*
>
> *pay with silver*

In contrast, substituting *with* for *in* in the second group works only if you add an indefinite article after *with*:

> *pay with a check/cheque*
>
> *pay with a credit card*

The underlying distinction at work here may be the difference between form of payment (cash, hard currency, dollars, etc.) and mode of transfer (check/cheque, credit card).